# Is it possible to command the Nintendo switch's joy cons with a PC?

Tags: bluetooth, macros, nintendo

I want to create a TAS that can play the Nintendo Switch games that are only compatible with the joy cons.

There are turbo pro controllers in the market but there is no turbo joy cons, so my next idea is one of two:

1. To use the Bluetooth to connect a devise that I could control with my PC and can be connected to the Nintendo switch via Bluetooth (or USB) and trick it into thinking that it is a joy con and not a pro controller.
2. Use the idea above but the devise is the joy con itself, in this case, I would have to connect the joy cont to the PC and command it while it is still paired with the Nintendo Switch

Is there any way to achieve what i'm looking for? Thanks in advise.

Also, if there is a better  branch in stack-overflow to post this question I will move it.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's already been done, and you'll need a product called vJoy.

https://www.pcgamesn.com/nintendo/nintendo-switch-joy-con-pc-guide

Comment: It looks like the post is for using the joycons as PC controllers, not to control them while still conected with the switch. What I want is to use my PC as joycons

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'd need to reverse engineer the communication protocol used by those controllers and then emulate that protocol with software. [Here](http://nilhcem.com/iot/reverse-engineering-simple-bluetooth-devices) is a resource I have found regarding RE bluetooth. Another one I have found [here](https://medium.com/@arunmag/my-journey-towards-reverse-engineering-a-smart-band-bluetooth-le-re-d1dea00e4de2). [Redfang](https://tools.kali.org/wireless-attacks/redfang) may help you in that endeavor, it is software that helps you find bluetooth addresses of devices that you you can't discover normally.

Another idea I would have is to open your controller and solder on some wires to a micro controller, such as an Arduino, Raspberry or something similar to the buttons and analogue controllers and 'input' the commands that way.

Unfortunately I can not offer you any more advice. I hope this helps in some way.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use [`JoyCon Droid`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rdapps.gamepad&hl=en) app in Android to controll the Nintendo Switch. If this app can work, it should be possible to make one as PC software too.

Luckily, there are a few easy ways to control Android from PC such as using [`AirDroid`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en_US) which allows you to touch the Android screen from PC. You can refer to [How to remote control Android device from a computer with AirDroid?](https://help.airdroid.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004121114-How-to-remote-control-Android-device-from-a-computer-with-AirDroid-). It can both mirror the screen and give you the touchscreen control, which you can utilize it to control the JoyCon Droid app.

---

I've just found another way which is to use a microcontroller as a USB controller [here](https://github.com/bertrandom/snowball-thrower).